# How to get height of a scrollable box to be reponsive

Tags: html, css, overflow, flexbox

So I am currently trying to get the height of a div to maintain ratio with the width when getting smaller/ bigger the images below better show what I am trying to do at the bottom of each image. Instead of the height overflowing like in image 2 I would like it be like image 1 I am just not sure how to do this here what I have so far.

[example state 1](http://postimg.org/image/4xpr1r8d3/) |
[example state 2](http://postimg.org/image/8nlpjnspj/)

HTML

```
<div class="browser-wrapper">
  <div class="browser">
    <div class="browser-header">
    </div>
    <div class="screen">
      <img src="assets/img/pieces/leakyroof.png" alt="">
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.browser-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; }

.browser {
  background-image: url("../../assets/img/broswer-outline.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 0%;
  width: 76%;
  height: 40em; }

.screen {
 width: 98.8%;
 max-height: 75.5%;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 margin: auto; }

.screen img {
  width: 100%; }

.browser-header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 5.7vw; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what technologies you want to use, if only css then I guess you can set your page in various ways by @media rule

For example :

```
@media screen and (min-height: 480px) {
    /*enter code here*/
}
```

You can set the media to be dependable on what device you are on.
More exmaples are shown here, 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

btw.

Try BootstrapCSS, it should be handy for you, but you can end up in remaking your layout.

Solution 2# Javascript

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').clientHeight;
document.getElementById('someDiv').offsetHeight;
```

Solution 3# jQuery

```
$('#someDiv').height();
```

Comment: I am currently using media queires it is just hard to target every screen size. I was hoping to avoid frameworks what element of bootstrap would solve the problem ? I am using jQuery though is there something that could be done using that maybe?

Comment: About bootstrap you need to know how grids work, go to this link and try to resize the window, you will see how nicely rectangles are scaling http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid  
While using javascript/jquery you need to add a listener on window resize, and mantain the size of your elements manualy

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
var heights = $("div.mySrvc ul li").map(function ()
{
    return $(this).height();
}).get(),

maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

$("div.mySrvc ul li").css('height',maxHeight);
```

});

Hope this help. this will get div of max height and apply same to all other one for responisve and same lenght.

Comment: Hey this does not seem to work it sets a height but it is still not enclosed within the the box